# cannot find php5-mysql in apt-get in ubuntu 15

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I am getting unable to locate package for

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

how to install it via ssh?

Comment: have you install before `php5` ? `sudo apt-get install php5`

Comment: Yes I have installed php5.